# Where do I find wireless drivers for ndiswrapper, for a Ralink card?

Tags: wireless, windows, ndiswrapper

I have some problems with Wifi at my Lenovo Z575. Under Win 7 Wifi works fine, so I wanted to install *exactly the same drivers* under Ubuntu with ndiswrapper.

My question is: where the drivers are located under Win 7? I tried to download the drivers from the vendor's site (Ralink) but with the downloaded drivers I still have some problems

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the current drivers from the Ralink Support website (download both XP and Windows 7 versions):

   http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501
2. Install Windows Wireless Drivers (ndiswrapper):

   - Open Software Center and search "Windows Wireless".
   - Click "More Info" on the Windows Wireless Drivers package.
   - Ensure that both Add-ons (ndiswrapper-dkms and ndiswrappe-source) are marked for install.
   - Click Install for the main Windows Wireless Drivers package.
3. Open Windows Wireless Drivers.
4. Type your administrative password.
5. Click "Install new driver" and go to the directory of the .inf file of your drivers and open it.
6. Install.
7. Reboot.

*** Note, if this does not work, remove the driver and try again with the other version of Windows driver. My setup, for example, will only work with the Windows 2000 version for some reason.***